# No 'pidfile' option in the configuration file [Prosody]

Tags: xmpp, prosody-im

I was using ejabberd as my XMPP server. Right now I just switched to Prosody for testing purpose. Installation and configuration everything goes fine. But while starting the openfire server like `sudo service prosody start` it raises me the error of

```
There is no 'pidfile' option in the configuration file, see http://prosody.im/doc/prosodyctl#pidfile
```

I went through the [pidfile doc](http://prosody.im/doc/prosodyctl#pidfile) link but cant find my solution how to overcome with this.

Right now my pidfile path is at `/var/run/prosody/prosody.pid` and documentation says we can change to the present directory too. I tried a lot and can't find solution.

Please help me with this and need some suggestions

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue with error on a centos

I had defined the VirtualHost above the pidfile definition.  I moved the VirtualHost after and service prosody start and it worked fine

Comment: My VirtualHost definition is below the pidfile definition and I still get the same error.

Comment: Did you mean above the pid?  Cause below the pid is a problem. Save and reboot the service

Comment: No, it is below the PID definition, but it is below the PID definition by default. Here is how the code looks like: https://pastebin.com/27Ev3rUc //EDIT: I've put it above the PID definition and it still throws the same error.